# gauss-law or gausss-law tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Apparently, it's [Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law), not (the) Gauss Law. I'm relying on Wikipedia here (and elsewhere), which sticks adamantly to the former. Please correct me in a comment if I'm wrong.

I think that to be consistent with all other such tags, e.g., [coulombs-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coulombs-law), [greens-functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greens-functions), [machs-principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machs-principle), [fermis-golden-rule](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fermis-golden-rule), [braggs-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braggs-law), it should be tagged by [gausss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gausss-law), not the current [gauss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauss-law).

It looks a bit funny though. :)

*Please downvote ([gauss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gauss-law)) or upvote ([gausss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gausss-law)) if you have an opinion.*

Comment: Or would Gauss' law also be correct English?

Comment: Wikipedia accepts Gauss' law and redirects it to Gauss's law. That makes me inclined to delete the question. Please advise.

Comment: Gausss looks really strange :-D

Comment: Perhaps we should say "Gauß's" instead...

Comment: But yes, @Gugg, I'm 99% sure the rule in English is as follows: "Always add `'s` in writing, unless the final `s` was there as part of pluralization." For pronunciation of the final `es` syllable, I believe it depends on whether there is 1 syllable total or more than 1; one case demands pronouncing the newly-added `s`, the other leaves it optional, and I can never remember which is which. I studied this at a young age trying to make my own first name possessive.

Comment: And now I think about it, there are exceptions to these rules for Biblical names, but, great though he may have been, Gauss was not a Biblical persona.

Comment: I concur with Chris here, in English one uses s-apostrophe whenever one wants to possessiveify a word ending in an s sound.

Comment: IMO "gauss-law" is good here because it is also known as "the gauss law". The serpentine gausss looks silly :p

Comment: What about gauss-apostrophe-s-law? Oops! Too many characters.!

Answer (score 1):

This has been thought of before. The tag is spelled as it is because it looks funny the other way, that's all. Of course if apostrophes were allowed in tag names, it would be a whole different matter.

Answer (score 0):

This has been thought of before! The tag should be spelled [gausss-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gausss-law) because 1) apostrophes and spaces aren't allowed in tag names and 2) it looks funny. That's all.